# Embedded Grafana in Gitlab not working via Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, gitlab, reverse-proxy, grafana

When trying to visit the url (as admin): https://gitlab.domain.com/-/grafana I am encountered with a 404 Page not found error.

So when trying to visit the Grafana monitoring (provided via GitLab) instance I am faced with a 404 Page not Found error.

Grafana is running on port 3000 so `curl localhost:3000` outputs:

`<a href="/-/grafana/login">Found</a>.`

I have tried adding the following location blocks to my Apache configuration

```
<Location /-/grafana>
ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</Location>
```

and

```
<Location /-/grafana>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000
</Location>
```

These are my apache configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gitlab.domain.com
  ServerSignature Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    Require all granted

    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on

  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =gitlab.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and for https:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/var/run/apache2/stapling_cache(128000)
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName gitlab.example.com
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    Require all granted

    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/
  </Location>


RequestHeader set Host "gitlab.example.com"
RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Ssl on
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
  RewriteEngine on

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately neither of the location blocks work. I have placed both blocks in both the port 80 apache configuration and port 443 configuration but I am still stuck with the 404 error page.